# Very large Redgate SQL script runs for a long time in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization, redgate

We are doing a migration using Redgate SQL Data Compare 12. It is producing scripts on the order of 800+ MB. We process the script using sqlcmd.

The exact command is:

```
sqlcmd -i [path to SQL script file] -a 32767 -d [db name] -x -o script<#>.log
```

This script is taking 10 1/2 hours to complete, but completes successfully. This script goes against many 10s of tables. There is a second script for a single table that is over 500 MB that only takes about 5-10 minutes to run that we run after the first one.

The server is a VM and has 16 GB of memory. From the SQL Server memory tab:

> Min memory = 8172
>
> Max memory = 2147483647

I'm not a dba, I'm a web dev. Any hints as to things I can Google to check to possibly make this thing run faster would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: without looking at the script. my guess is indexes may be causing slow insert in tables.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to say why a script of size 800 MB takes longer time  and 500MB Script takes less time with out seeing the script..

One approach is to check for wait stats..below DMV will give you hints

```
select status,blocking_session_id,wait_resource,
wait_type,last_wait_type from
sys.dm_Exec_requests
```

The above DMV provides info on wait type,time and blocking status

The above DMV requires sessionid to be passed,if you have only script running,then you don't need sessionid,but if the server is being used, you can use below dmv to get sessionid

```
select * from sys.dm_exec_sessions 
where PROGRAM_NAME='sqlcmd'
```

Comment: I should run that SQL while the long running script is running, right?

Comment: Unfortunately, the content of the scripts are confidential. But if there are things that you think I could look for in the scripts, I can check on that.

Comment: Try checking the DMV to see if there are locking/blockings first.if there are no locking/blockings then checking the script would make sense